# redux-saga takeEvery only called with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga

I have a container that dispatches the following action:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => { 
    return { 
        getPageTree: (siteId) => { 
            dispatch(getPageTree(siteId)); 
        }
    }
} 

const explorer = connect(
    mapStateToProps, 
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Explorer);
```

In my component (to which props are sent through the container) I've added:

```
componentWillMount(){ 
    setTimeout(() => this.props.getPageTree()); 
}
```

The saga:

```
function* fetchPageTree(action){ 
    try{ 
        const data = yield call(Api.fetchPageTree, action.payload.url); 
        yield put({type: 'FETCH_SUCCEEDED', data}); 
    }catch(error){ 
        yield put({type: 'FETCH_FAILED', error})
    } 
}

export function* watchFetchData(){ 
    console.log('watch'); 
    yield* takeEvery('GET_PAGETREE', fetchPageTree); 
    console.log('finish watch'); 
}
```

The saga watcher calls the `fetchPageTree` properly using `takeEvery` when applying `setTimeout` in the component, but doesn't execute `fetchPageTree` without.
No error gets thrown either.

Any idea about the cause?

Edit:
The index.es6 file contains the following initialization logic, but is overall standard:

```
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware(); 
const store = createStore(
    appReducers, //Combined reducers 
    applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
); 

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
        </Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('zp-app')
)
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
```

Comment: What does getPageTree(siteId) return?

What do you mean by applying setTimeout?

Comment: @baisang It is an action creator returning an action object to get the pageTree. I think the problem is related to the fact that the component methods get called before the saga. setTimeout lets the other processes finish before the function gets run. Not sure how to solve this though currently.

Comment: Are you sure the action outputs of setTimeout() and getPageTree(siteId) are the same format?

Comment: @html_programmer did you ever solve this side-effect/async issue? I've got the same problem where the action is called but the saga take latest is never triggered but works if I use a set timeout in the mount method.

Answer (score 0):

When did you call `render` function?
If the render function is called after `sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);`, it should work wo deferred call of `this.props.getPageTree`.